# css: rendering page numbers in HTML footer for printed PDF page (Chromium)

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, chromium, puppeteer

My workflow for dynamically generating PDF:

1. Handlebars compiles HTML
2. I add a "fake footer" to this HTML using the CSS trick with `position: fixed` on a normal `<div>` element that actually appears in HTML only once
3. Puppeteer (so, headless Chromium browser) is used to generate a PDF out of this HTML page (I know the git version of Puppeteer has automatic footer insertion; for complicated reasons I am stuck with the npm version which does not support this yet).

My problem is how to add page numbers in this footer. I have tried the `counter-reset` + `counter-increment` solution, but this does not increment the page counter since, from its point of view, there is only one HTML element on which it is applied.

So I get a footer that says "Page 1" on each page of the generated PDF.

The HTML element:

```
...
<div class="page-footer"></div>
...
```

The CSS styling:

```
.report {
  counter-reset: pageIndex 0;

  .page-footer:before {
    content: "Page: " counter(pageIndex);
    counter-increment: pageIndex +1;
  }

  .page-footer {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: solid 1px;
  }
  ...
}
```

Does something like this actually work on Chromium, or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your tools, but I've done some HTML to PDF stuff myself.
Sounds like your single HTML is getting rendered with the page number in the footer (correctly, as there's only one page at this point), and the separate PDF pages are being created through a 'print to document' type conversion.

My suggestion then would be to pop your existing CSS rule into an `@media print` query, this should number the pages as they are created by the PDF print process.

Comment: Yes, it's a headless browser that renders the HTML to PDF. I'm not sure that the [at]media is taken into account in my case (I'm actually editing an *.scss file that is then compiled via Sass to a *.css): added this in my styling, just for testing purposes:
[at]media print {
    body { background-color: #ff0000; }
  }, but I don't see any change (I'm using the correct 'at' sign in code, but can't use it here in the comment).

Comment: But perhaps something is overriding the style, I'll have to check in detail (6000+ lines in generated css...). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've been having a bit of a look around... Try adding an `@page:after` rule to your media query and pop the page numbering in there. Not sure if it will work (it's a bit of a hack, `:after` is for generated page margins!), but worth a go?

Comment: @Cristina, just had a thought that might save you a lot of hunting. Try popping the `.page-footer{}` rule, as is, into the `@media print` query. There will be no overriding rule for the page (it's a custom element) so it is performing no additional styling, it's taking the content directly from the `screen` render (your default CSS) where there is only one 'page' - hence the 'Page 1' (which is correct for screen) on every PDF 'page'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out!

Comment: Update: we ended up abandoning the `position: fixed` idea for the footer, since nothing we tried worked. Now we are generating the footer for every page and the CSS counter idea is functional. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: can you show us what you had fixed, i got the same issue?